# Change value while clicking a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, rss

I'm tring to build a mobile app. Getting rss content from different web sites. But there are a lot of web sites, and I want to list only user wants to see.

For example;

```
<a href="#" class="website1">Web Site 1</a>
<a href="#" class="website2">Web Site 2</a>
<a href="#" class="website3">Web Site 3</a>
```

- if website1 clicked rss address = website1.com/feed
- if website2 clicked rss address = website2.com/feed
- if website3 clicked rss address = website3.com/feed

default rss address = website1.com/feed

I dont't use checkbox or radiobox. How can I do it?

Comment: why don't you change the ```href``` to "website1.com/feed" , "website2.com/feed" etc. Is this not what you want?

Comment: using http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEk/FeedEk.html plugin. I need to give a new rss address each time.

Comment: BOOM! that should now be working as desired below. Check the  jsfiddle below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsfiddle and code below will give you the feed address you are looking for on each click. There was an issue loading the jquery plugin, however I fixed this so it now works in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/048uc1ts/8/ - this should now be displaying the desired information.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var designrss = 'http://news.layervault.com/?format=rss';             
    $('a').click(function() {

        var designrss;

        var className = $(this).prop('class');

        if(className == 'designernews') {
            designrss = 'http://news.layervault.com?format=rss';
        } else if(className == 'sidebar') {
            designrss = 'http://feeds.sidebar.io/SidebarFeed';
        } else if(className == 'swissmiss') {
            designrss = 'http://feeds2.feedburner.com/Swissmiss';                        
        } else {
            designrss = 'http://news.layervault.com?format=rss';
        }

        alert(designrss)
        $('#divRss').FeedEk({
            FeedUrl:designrss
        });

    })

    });
```

Dependant on what link you click the plugin then provides the appropriate feed.

Comment: @sakarya see updated jsfiddle and code above. For your ```if/else``` statements you need to use ```==``` as opposed to ```=``` as this just sets the variable value. I believe the above should work. Let me know if not and we can make further changes

Comment: $('a').click(function() is this true. I've menu elements that they have a tag, and rss content title elements have a tag. when i click sidebar or swismiss (or another) content not change.

Comment: @sakarya I think the issue in jsfiddle is that there is a problem loading the plugin. Follow the exact new code above and it should work, at least it does for me. Please let me know if you get it working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76804/discussion-between-paul-fitzgerald-and-sakarya).